# I need to store the all Saturdays and Sundays in one array and Reaming as another string Array

Tags: java, android, calendar, arrays

```
public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int year = 2012;

        // put the month you want
        int month = Calendar.MARCH;

        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, 1);
        do {
            int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
            if (day == Calendar.SATURDAY || day == Calendar.SUNDAY) {
                System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            }
            cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
        }  while (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) == month);
    }
```

By the above code i am getting all saturdays and sundays in a given month .I want store all these days in an array and the other days in another String array.

Comment: Can u please explain your requirement bit more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by reaming days, but if I understand the first part of your question correctly, this should work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int year = 2012;

    // put the month you want
    int month = Calendar.MARCH;

    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, 1);
    List<String> saturdaysAndSundays = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> otherDays = new ArrayList<String>();
    do {
        int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        String dayInMonth = Integer.toString(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        if (day == Calendar.SATURDAY || day == Calendar.SUNDAY) {
            saturdaysAndSundays.add(dayInMonth);
        } else {
            otherDays.add(dayInMonth);
        }
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
    }  while (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) == month);
    //In case you really want an array:
    String[] array = saturdaysAndSundays.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

Comment: reaming days is nothing but except Saturdays and Sundays